# Fetch data from nested mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection like the following. I wan to get the users data only where fb_user_id is 2001.

How can I do this in PHP?

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("5024db89b7ac1c900e000000"),
"title": "This is a title",

"users": [
            {
              "name": "John",
              "email": "john@example.com",
              "fb_user_id": "1000"
            },
            {
              "name": "Jack",
              "email": "jack@example.com",
              "fb_user_id": "2001"
            },

        ]

}
```

Comment: I tried like this $data = $collection->findOne(array("title" => "This is a title", "users.fb_user_id" => '2001'), array("users")); But it will return all users information, I want only user information whose fb_user_id is 2001. Please help me

Answer (score 2):

Your could use the following mongodb query

```
{ "title.users.fb_user_id" : 2001 }
```

I case of more complex query you could use elemMatch query operator

```
{ 
   "title.users" : {$elemMatch : { "fb_user_id" : 2001, "name" : "John" } }
}
```

Something like that. Hope it helps

Comment: Here is reference http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-ValueinanArray

But it`s also possible to find it via "title.users.fb_user_id" : 2001

$elemMatch is for more that 1 expression
will update the answer

Comment: Oh, I feel so silly. I didn't have my glasses on when I read your comment the first time, and completely misread your answer. Yes, you are correct. I didn't notice the outer top and bottom brackets, so I wasn't sure what you were trying to accomplish with only a "title.users": {...}. My apologies!

Comment: No problem, you actually help me to answer better for that questions. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I tried like this $data   =   $collection->findOne(array("title" => "This is a title", "users.fb_user_id" => '2001'), array("users")); But it will return all users information, I want only user information whose fb_user_id is 2001. Please help me

Comment: You can setup fields set to return, but in any case it will be in your document schema, for example you have an object {a:{b:{c:123}}} and you run query findOne({"a.b.c" : 123 },{"a.b.c" : 1"}) here {"a.b.c" : 1"} is the setup which fields to return. But you will get in in the schema of parent object. Like "title" : {"users" : [ ] } and so on

Comment: Was my answer helpful? If so, please accept it, or ask more questions

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to return one match found within an embedded array (and not the rest of the array) you will need to either:

- handle this in your application code (iterate the `users` array and find the matching element)
- use the new positional operator support ([SERVER-828](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/server-828)) which will be available in the 2.2 version of MongoDB.

Example using the positional operator in the `mongo` 2.2 shell:

```
> db.mycoll.find({'users.fb_user_id':"2001"}, {_id:0, 'users.fb_user_id.$':1})
{
    "users" : [
        {
            "name" : "Jack",
            "email" : "jack@example.com",
            "fb_user_id" : "2001"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: NB: MongoDB 2.2rc0 release candidate has been available for testing since mid-July.